# glxinfo Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Tags: 16.04, xorg, opengl

I'm attempting to build a minimal system using Ubuntu Server 16.04 and installing X and Openbox to run a single Qt-based OpenGL application. I went this route instead of something like Lubuntu as I'd like to have almost no desktop except for my application. I've got X up and running and can use XTerm and other non-OpenGL applications but my OpenGL application won't run and I'm receiving the following error when I try to run glxinfo:

`glxinfo Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig`

I've read through many questions and threads reporting this issue but none have been able to help me solve my problem. A lot of the problems seem to be related to Nvidia driver which I've removed using:

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

My X log report doesn't show any errors. At the very least I'd like to have my system use Mesa OpenGL which I have installed by running:

`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri`

The graphics card driver is Intel i915. Does anyone know how to get OpenGL up and running when starting from a Ubuntu Server install?

Comment: Why did you installed nvidia drivers in the first place if you graphics card is an Intel?

Comment: @Simon, I've run into this same issue. Have you solved it?

Comment: @user545424 yes, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My particular problem was caused by trying to start X directly as a service using SystemD without logging a user in. I refactored my setup to have SystemD automatically log in with the following getty override script:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noissue --autologin {{ username }} %I $TERM
Type=idle
```

saved in `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf`. I then started X from the user's `bash_profile` by running `/usr/bin/startx`.