# Nvidia driver for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I really need for my work to use Nvidia driver. My NVIDIA card is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti and I find in http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx that driver version 390.59 is the driver I should install.

After download the driver I run it and I have this error show in the image throw the link:

[image: after I run the driver that I download from the official web]

Answer (score 0):

You must open a Console using next keys: **`CTRL`** + **`ALT`** +  **`T`** change file to execute permission using next command: **`chmod a+x /path/to/nvidia/driver`** then from console: **`/path/to/nvidia/driver`**

Also you need to stop the GUI (Desktop) before install the driver : 
**`CTRL`** + **`ALT`** +  **`F1`**  for GDM3 use: **`sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop`** or for Lightdm: **`sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop`** then run the install: **`sudo /path/to/nvidia/driver`**

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have do all this and the installation completed successfully after that I reboot my PC . But when I write my true password and enter this show my login again and again without enter to the desktop :( any help ?!

Comment: The cause is when you upgrade something related to .Xauthority with sudo, root will own this file and you cannot login as a user. Just press Ctrl + Alt + F1, login with your username and: 

sudo chown [your_username] /home/[your_username]/.Xauthority

Comment: sudo chown user:user /home/user/.Xauthority replace user with your own user

Comment: My user name is ahmad I wrote : " sudo chown ahmad:ahmad /home/ahmad/ .Xauthority" and I reboot after it and I have the same problem again ... ;(

Comment: try, if you have lightdm: sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm or for gdm3: sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3, if that not work try to delete .Xauthority : rm /home/ahmad/.Xauthority then login again

Comment: if none work you can try to install: nvidia-dkms-390 and  nvidia-driver-390 but first you need to uninstall current driver here it's a link how to remove it https://askubuntu.com/questions/219942/how-to-uninstall-manually-installed-nvidia-drivers then install via apt: sudo apt install nvidia-dkms-390 nvidia-driver-390

Comment: Thanks , Yes I install Nvidia 390 and enter to the system . The last question please how I can verify the I am working at the Nvidia card not intel I wrote nvidia-settings in terminal and I have this "Error: unable to load info from any available system" ((this is my previous problem :( ))

Comment: please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card

Comment: or simple:  glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer*"  and if there say nvidia it's ok

Comment: try to use: sudo prime-select nvidia to select nvidia then: nvidia-settings

Comment: the output of ((glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer*")): is ""Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig""    I tried ((sudo prime-select nvidia)) and it say : ""Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['nvidia-390', 'nvidia-390']
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['nvidia-390', 'nvidia-390']
Info: the nvidia profile is already in use""  after that I write ((nvidia-settings)) and the output :   ""ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system""  Is that mean that I am working on nvidia but I cant open settings ??!!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/918265/glxinfo-error-couldnt-find-rgb-glx-visual-or-fbconfig

Comment: I have this as output of (( glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer*"))   "OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center 
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Kabylake GT2"  I Despaired to find solution :((.

Comment: have you found solution ?

Comment: I am trying to solve until now , I tried Nvidia-linux-x86_64-396.18.run compatible with my Nvidia card and I have the same error ;(